# Multiple Row with Fix number of Records In React

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs

I have 9 records of product image in localstorage and now I want to display that images like gallary view. I use table and map array to display image and apply `array.slice(0,length)` so all the record fetch but all images will be display in only one row. I want to display fix number of image in each row, i.e. each row have 5 records like this.

```
      {this.state.productdata.slice(0,this.state.productdata.length).map((item, index) => (
          <td>                                                                                                                            
             <div className="row" >                                                                                                             
            <div className="card">
              <div class="cardbody">
            <img src={item.productimage} onClick={this.MoreViewHandle.bind(this,item.productid)} height="250px" width="150px"></img>
            </div></div></div>
            </td>

        ))}
       </tr>   

      </table>
```

I want same number of records in each row. Like first row display first 5 records, second row display 6-10 records and so on..

Comment: Don't know too much about React but this logic will be useful... `if(index+1 % 5 === 0){'</tr><tr>'}`. If index value +1 is divisible by 5, row will be break and start by adding `</tr><tr>` and `if(index+1 == this.state.productdata.length){'</tr>'}` when index value +1 is similar with data length only `</tr>` will be added. Remove `</tr>`(closing row) before `</table>` in your code. Because, `</tr>` (closing row) will be added by above logic.

Comment: I understand little bit but not some can you please provide me full code with condition ?

Comment: Do you have any parent class in your `<table>`?

Comment: <div> then <table> no any classname apply in table but Imagecad class is in div 
.ImageCard  {
 flex-direction: row;

  padding-left:15px;
  margin-right:2px;
  z-index: 9;
  
  
}

Comment: I have post my answer. If you can't add class into `<table>`, just grab any parent `<div>` class of the `<table>` and put it in `CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid:

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  // creates a row of items that are dynamically sized (1fr, fr === free space)
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  // adds gutters to rows and columns, grid gaps can be added to each individually, also
  grid-gap: 16px;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/sodapop/pen/GRRpqgR

Learn more here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I apply this css but that is not worked all records still display in one row.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you using this CSS on top of existing CSS? If so, remove the pre-existing CSS and use grid in its place.

Comment: I am run this code with Chrome and I am remove previous css and apply this but still not working.

Comment: Could you post your css?

Comment: .row .card{
    display: grid;
    /* creates a row of items that are dynamically sized (1fr, fr === free space)*/
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    /* adds gutters to rows and columns, grid gaps can be added to each individually, also*/
    grid-gap: 16px;
  }
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
  left: 15px;
  display: grid;
  margin-right: 273px;
}

Comment: .cardbody{
   width:180px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   display: grid;
   height: 300px;
   grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
   grid-template-rows: 100px 300px;
   grid-gap: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .cardbody .img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
 }

Comment: The problem is, you're adding it to card. It needs to be on the parent of card, per my example. The parent controls the pattern and flow of the children.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row{
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-start;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.card{
width:250px;
height:150px
}


.row img{
object-fit:cover;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this 'img-gallery' class in your `<table>` like this `<table class="img-gallery">`
then add below `CSS`.

```
table.img-gallery tr{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
table.img-gallery tr td{
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
}
```